# Increasing margin of left side tag/number in amsmath align enviroment

Tags: indentation, amsmath, align

I asked this on the lyx user list but haven't got an answer
(http://marc.info/?l=lyx-users&m=137891444218650&w=2).

I would like to include text lines in align environment using 'leqno' option of amsmath package.

This inserts numbers in front of each line and aligns the lines
giving an output like this:

```
|(1)                aligned text = line
|(2)                   something = other something
|(3)                         ab  = CD
```

The | represents the left margin (specified for text pages).

How could I set the exact position of the number, for example to move it to the right, closer to the aligned lines (or increase the margin for the number)? I find the space between numbers and aligned text too big. Instead of the above I would like to get something like this:

align environment 1:

```
|              (1)  A. aligned text = line
|              (2)        something = other something
|              (3)              ab  = CD
```

align environment 2:

```
|        (1)                       something = other something
|        (2)  B. this is longer aligned text = linedifferent 
|        (3)                             ab  = CD
```

See that I have different align environments and the indentations have to be the same within the same align but should be different between different aligns, depending on the length of the aligned lines. I would prefer to set the distance
between the number and the left edge of the aligned stuff (labels A. and B. above), and the indentation should be adjusted according to this.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

bcsikos

Comment: do you want the equation number indented on all numbered equations, or only on certain specific lines?  and if on all numbered lines, do you want the indentation always to be the same, or might some be different from others?

Comment: I want all numbers to be indented. I edited my question to make it clearer what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Plan B:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{align}
a&=b\\a&=b\\a&=b
\end{align}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\makeatletter
\def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{\hspace{2cm}\m@th\normalfont#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{align}
a&=b\\a&=b\\a&=b
\end{align}


\noindent X\dotfill X

\end{document}
```

---

Plan A:

Generally the way to control margins in LaTeX is via a list structure (see how `quote` is defined in `article` class)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{align}
a&=b\\a&=b\\a&=b
\end{align}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{list}{}{\setlength\leftmargin{4cm}}\item\relax
\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{align}
a&=b\\a&=b\\a&=b
\end{align}
\end{list}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\end{document}
```

Comment: In this solution the whole stuff goes to the right. I would like the aligned lines to be kept centered and only the numbers get closer to the left side of the aligned lines.

Comment: @bcsikos Oh OK see update

Comment: note that, while this works with `article`, it won't work with `amsart` because of the editorial decision that the position of display math won't be affected by the indentations of list environments.  a different mechanism would have to be devised to get the requested effect with any ams document class.

Comment: @barbarabeeton true of the original plan a but not of the updated plan b (which is what the OP wanted I think)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- replace `article` with `amsart` and run your example.  (i just did.)  if you get indented equation numbers, please let me know -- that will be a bug that needs to be attended to.

Comment: @barbarabeeton the plan B one at the top of the answer, yes the numbers indent.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- okay, so i haven't learned to read the alphabet.  yes, that does work -- for the short lines you used in the example.  but the indentation doesn't adjust automatically; see the example for "environment 2" in the original question.

Comment: @barbarabeeton well no because that would be too weird but if you replaced `2cm` by calc package `\textwidth-widthof{$\displaystyle the longest expression in the group$}` then it would

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- Well, it's getting closer. As Barbara points out the long lines are pushed to the right. I don't understand how the distance of the push is calculated. I 'd like the distance between the tag and the left side of the aligned stuff really small, similar to itemize or enumerate lists.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- continued from previous edit: I also tried the code \textwidth-widthof{$\displaystyle CCCCCCCCCCCCCC \&= DDDDD$} but it did not work. See image: [align-image](http://i41.tinypic.com/20zelxz.jpg)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle --I replaced "widthof" with "\widthof" but it's still not working.

Comment: @bcsikos It's not clear what you want to do, in any case a string involving a literal `&` is unrelated to the widths of table cells using `&` as a cell separator (all you can do is measure the natural width _widest_  cells) and if necessary add these together, but making the equation numbers move around depending on the width of the equation is _so_ weird.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle --I uploaded an image [here](http://i39.tinypic.com/v4mf.jpg) showing what I want to achieve. I made it in word so it is not very accurate. It might be weird but the aligned environments are on different pages in the document.